# Why is but used at the end of a sentence (below, a sentence from Wikipedia)

Tags: meaning-in-context

Christmas should be a time of joy, but for thousands of people sleeping rough, in tents or on public transport it will be anything but.

Comment: Read it as "...  it will be anything but **that**." (other than that/ except that -- it's no 'time of joy'). HTH.

Answer (score 1):

"anything but" is a common idiom.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/dictionary/english/anything-but

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anything%20but

Comment: We can use comments to post these.